# Is it possible to create custom UIViews for iOS and use them inside XIBs?

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface

I know you can drag a UIView in a XIB and then set its class to a custom type.

But is it possible to create custom UIViews which could later be used in other projects and eventually dragged from the Objects list and having a custom visualisation that properly represents that UIView subclass?

Comment: Given that you can drag the whole VCs along with xib draggin .h .m and .xib into the new project does not work for you? It seems a whole lot cheaper that maintaining an xcode plugin in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way: http://www.inline-studios.com/developer/articles/1-Xcode_4_Interface_Builder_Plugins/ but it's both complicated and might break as it is not documented by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the current version of Xcode.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: The question was "is it possible to..." And I (accurately) answered "no." I'm not sure what you find unclear about that.

Comment: I didn't say it was clear, it is not what we expect an answer to be on stackoverflow. We expect not only to say *'you can't'*, but we expect that you provide tips how you can, give links to sources which describes something. If you gave more information, it was a correct answer, now it is a comment. More info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/177764

Comment: @WouterJ, you are conflating the concept of a *good answer*, with that of an *answer*.  Those two things are not the same.  An answer that explains why the answer is *"No"* might be a *better* answer than this, but it doesn't mean this is not an answer (and should be a comment).